# what do i need to develop an asterisk script to auto create and assign extensions to clients who have joined my network

Tags: voip, asterisk, cisco

the idea is having a LAN with an Asterisk server installed such that if someone connects to the network, the asterisk server gets to know about the 'joined client event' connection and consequently creates credentials necessary for that client  to place a voip call to another person on the network.
am new to both voip and asterisk, so please bear with me for i dont know if even such a function is in existance.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need read about asterisk realtime architecture.

But anyway u need write voip client to support auto-config.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it really helps, about the voip auto client, am intending to use an already existing one like xlite.